How does prepareForDisplay work and why does it work without using the decodedImage
I am trying to load an image from a url but it causes major lags in my app due to the amount of images I am loading. I am now calling "prepareForDisplay" on the image I get from inputting UIImage(contentsOfFile: url) and I think that fixed my performance issues. I am using the following code but want to understand why:
class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
     uiImage.prepareForDisplay { decodedImage in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.image = uiImage
        }
    }
}


I never use decodedImage but somehow the code still displays no lags when setting it to the uiImage, is this because by the time we are setting image we have already retrieved that new object? If I set an imageView to decodedImage I seem to get a [Decompressor] Error -17102 decompressing image -- possibly corrupt and none of the images appear.

Images are compressed in various ways depending on the image type and method of saving. (JPEG images are an obvious example, but PNGs are also compressed, and SVG and other vector images are sent as vector drawing commands that have to be rendered into pixels.)
I strongly suspect that prepareForDisplay() renders the image as a bitmap at the device's native resolution, and returns the fully expanded image. It almost certainly also caches the resulting fully expanded image.
If you call prepareForDisplay() and ignore the result, the cached image will likely still be available in memory and so you will render even the original image quickly because the system doesn't have to decompress it again. However, caches are subject to flushing, so you might end up with another long pause at some point in the future if you discard the resulting image.

I am still seeing logs in my xcode that said there was a Decompressor Error, but I verify whether ULR(contentsOfFIle) outputted a valid image and all the images I want to show are appearing in my view. When I step through it I see that the error is thrown once I am in the prepareForDisplay function, my assumption is since I am setting my image to the original image the image is still getting displayed but the decompressedImage is never generated correctly. Is there a better way to go about this and still have the performance improvements?
